# How to disable opensshd's self-introductory banner

Tags: ssh, bsd

I have opensshd listening on the non-standard tcp port of 2222. In **sshd_config** I have ...

```
Banner none
VersionAddendum none
```

If from a client host I do a **telnet ip.of.server 2222** then I see the service displaying a message introducing itself like so ...

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
```

Is there a way to prevent this happening and instruct the openssh daemon not to reveal itself? I would prefer if *"wandering"* connections could not learn what is listening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal identification string for the ssh protocol is:

```
SSH-2.0-
```

however OpenSSH will always send at least `OpenSSH_*.*`. If you want a more stealth behaviour you have several options:

1. You can patch and recompile **openssh** so that the server waits for the client's identification string before sending its own (cf. the [sshd_exchange_identification](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/71508e06fab14bc415a79a08f5535ad7bffa93d9/sshd.c#L367) function). If the client's identification string does not start with `SSH`, it's a bogus client and you can close the connection. It might break some clients (if they wait for the server's identification), but it should not break the OpenSSH client. A portscanner will not be able to deduce the server's protocol, unless he sends a valid client authentication string.
2. Install and configure **nginx**. Normally it is a `HTTP/HTTPS` (proxy) server) and it has an [ssl preread module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html), which is used to apply different configurations to different `TLS` clients (based on their version and other parameters). However if you connect to **nginx** using a protocol it does not understand, it will set `$ssl_preread_protocol` to the empty string and you can redirect the connection to an SSH server. If a portscanner tries to use `TLS`, **nginx** will serve him a web page. If he tries any other protocol, he'll receive **OpenSSH**'s identification string.
3. There is a small protocol multiplexer ([sslh](https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh)), which guessed a client's protocol and redirects it to the correct server.

These options should answer your question, but it do not believe the **security through obscurity** is the way to go (besides port `2222` is not very original). You'd be better off:

1. disabling password logins,
2. using something like [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to limit the amount of brute force attacks.

Comment: Your insights are much appreciated, Piotr! I did consider 1), but I did not know about 3) and I certainly would not have thought of 2) while these are both sensible options. I very much agree with your perspective. The service allows pubkey auth only, and it is not on tcp 2222 -for the purposes of this post here it was a self-explanatory example and obviously worked well.